error TS2322: Type 'string | number | Date' is not assignable to type 'Date' on a project that has just been upgraded to Angular 16
I have a project that I have just upgraded from Angular 11 to Angular 16. In Angular 11, I had all my DTO models created with the NPM package "ng-swagger-gen" from the Web API's Swagger JSON file. "ng-swagger-gen" is generating a string member in the TypeScript DTO model for a DateTime field in my C# class that is part of the Web API.
I have a DTO class for an entity called Action. The action's start time is declared as a null-able DateTime property field, in my C# class, on the Web API's side:
[DataMember] public DateTime? actionStartDate { get; set; }

"ng-swagger-gen" generates an optional field in the TypeScript model it created in my Angular project:
actionStartDate?: string;

In my HTML, I have a popover form where I update an action. For the action's start date, I use a DateBox widget from the DevExtreme API:
<dx-date-box type="date"
                    displayFormat="shortdate"
                    [(value)]="updateAction.actionStartDate"
                    [min]="today">
                    <!-- [displayFormat]="{type: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}" -->
         <dx-validator>
           <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="The action's start date is a required field"></dxi-validation-rule>
         </dx-validator>
       </dx-date-box>

This whole approach worked perfectly fine in Angular 11, but now, when I upgraded to Angular 16, I am getting an error when I try to compile the project ("ng build"):
error TS2322: Type 'string | number | Date' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

28 [(value)]="updateAction.actionStartDate"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
29 [min]="today">

Interestingly enough, Visual Studio Code does not flag that error as such (there is no red wiggly line underneath the binding of the widget's value to the actionStartDate field of the action to be updated:

To confuse me further, I have other situations where the binding variable in my component is actually defined as a 'Date' and I still get the same error.
Why is this happening and what is the solution?
Thanks,
Eddie

Turns out this can be resolved by turning off the "strictTemplates" flag in the "angularCompilerOptions" section inside the tsconfig.json file, like this:
"angularCompilerOptions": {
   "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
   "strictInjectionParameters": true,
   "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
   "strictTemplates": false
 }

The alternative would be to keep the strictTemplates flag on and declare all variable bound to the value of the dx-date-box control as "string | number | Date". That does not work for me because those types would be overwritten every time I refresh my DTO models using ng-swagger-gen.
